# How to extract month from a string/varchar column in SQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, extract

I have a string/varchar column that I want to extract month. I first convert it to timestamp and try to extract the month, but it did not work. Can you please help?

created_at = "2013-01-01 20:59:39"

```
select month(created_at_new)
from(
SELECT
  *
  ,created_at::timestamp as created_at_new
FROM tutorial.yammer_users) as temp
```

I have tried DATEPART('month', created_at::timestamp) and strftime('%m', created_at_new). But no luck :(

Comment: did you try STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%m/%d/%Y') ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  You have tagged MySQL.  Your sample query uses Postgres conventions.  And what you have "tried" is code or SQL Server and SQLite.  Thoroughly confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL have function EXTRACT for this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM  TIMESTAMP '2013-11-01 20:59:39');
```

[DB Fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=b4caecf4a87e008cb3785750496a7155&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Answer (score 0):

How about just using substring?

```
select substr(created_at_now, 6, 2) as month
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! EXTRACT(month from created_at::timestamp)